# AJAX Not Loading JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to do a simple GET request with an acronym finder API but for some reason the JSON is not being returned. Here is the code:

```
   $.ajax('http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=DOD', {
    crossDomain:true, 
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If I visit the url directly in my browser, I can easily see the requested JSON, but my Chrome console  only returns:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=DOD&callback=jQuery1111025898682116530836_1417074190743&_=1417074190744".
```

The Chrome Debugger network tab indicates that the correct file was downloaded but why isn't the JSON being logged to the console?

Comment: Are they accepting JSONP requests?

Comment: For JSONP, what should be downloaded is an actual piece of Javascript that makes a function call and passes the data to that function call.  Is that what you see in the network tab?  If it's just a piece of JSON, then that isn't JSONP.

Comment: I just checked and `http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=DOD` returns json, not jsonp.

Comment: I am afraid you can't use that API as 1) they don't support callback means no JSONP, 2) cross domain policy as they do not have Access Control Allow Origin: * or list of sites

Comment: jfriend009 - I'm a bit new to this. How can you tell if it's returning JSON or JSONP?

Comment: LShetty - How would one actually use this API then?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the response MIME type is 'text/plain'. But it is expecting a Script MIME type.

[image]

So you need to setup your response at backend `dictionary.py` (if it is under your control). Add content-type `"application/x-javascript"` to the response header. Something similar to (in Java):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/fake")
public void testFake(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String callback = request.getParameter("jsonpcallback");
    SimpleJson json = new SimpleJson("Success", 0);
    JSONObject resultJSON = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
    response.setContentType("application/x-javascript");   // Set content-type to "application/x-javascript"
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    if (callback == null) {
        out.println("{error: 'Callback function is not defined.'}");
    } else
        out.println(callback + "(" + resultJSON.toString(1, 1) + ")");
}
```

Comment: I don't have control of the dictionary.py file (it's an external API). In this case, is there anything I could do to change that response header?

Comment: @docta_faustus The host of `http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=DOD` should allow cross-origin requests by setting the response header in code or in server (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *), to allow cross-origin access. Otherwise, I suspect that the APIs are not intended for public access.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
$.ajax('http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=DOD', {
  crossDomain:true, 
  dataType: "json", 
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```